# Has Jet/ACE improved its concurrency and stability issues since JET 3.5?

Tags: ms-access, jet, ms-jet-ace

I am familiar with using JET 3.5 as a backend.  There are noticable stability and concurrency issues with this version of the database engine.  There is also a 1GB limit on the MDB file.

Has JET (or ACE as it is now called) improved in this regard since then?

Answer (score 1):

One improvement: Jet 4 and ACE have a 2 GB limit on the size of the database file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any been a specific changes here. At the end of the day when you are dealing with the file share system, and have multiple users editing the same file sitting on a hard drive, then you are inherently using a situation in which additional caution is required.

I've run multiuser systems in Access with some clients of mine for about 10 years with  a JET back end. They have about 5 users, the application is medium in size (160 forms, about 35,000 lines of VBA code). The application has about 55 or 60 VERY related tables since I have a good normalize designs and I am relying on engine level referential integrity.

Mind you most tables are quite small, say 75,000 records and their detail child records are 100,000 + rows. So this is rather small and very lightweight application. However for this client in 10+ years I not had one corruption or problem with 5 users on the phone using this software for reservations all day long. I would say it been rock solid.

However, as noted, I have a good setup, know what I doing, and have done all of the correct things that competent developers are supposed to do (split database, and a bunch of other good practices are in place).

However, if one has a poor network setup, has poor development practices and a poor setup for Access, then usually the best approach is to switch over to SQL server (a good half or more of my applications use SQL server – I use the free edition of SQL with Access as the front end).

So without good development practices then you can do what lesser developers do and simply use a server based system such as SQL server.  In other words SQL server is MORE forgiving to poor designs and poor setups. So the less you know and the less competent the developers are, then the better off they are to use to SQL server.

However you should also keep in mind that for access 2010, you do have the option of web publishing, and this architecture is based on Microsoft's cloud computing initiative.

This means in a fact that you could publish your Access database and have a million users hit the web site at the same time. The reason of course is because you using Microsoft's galactic massive server farm that runs your software now and your data is NOT stored in a file share access file. This means you quite much have unlimited scalability in terms number of users.

So here is an access application of mine I used, but then used the new publishing option in A2010 - note in the following video at the halfway point I switch to running the Access application 100% in a browser:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

There is no activeX or silver light used – that above was 100% developed on my desktop using MS Access an no other tools.

It also important to note that when talking about Access, you are not limited to using a "file share" and you can use Access to design and build the application, but the back end data can be now cloud based (SQL Azure) or with web publishing then office 365 or SharePoint. 
MS access is the development tool, and allows you to choose oracle or SQL server or the so called JET database engine (actually the new version object is now called ACE).

So to be clear at the end of the day it was use of the JET database engine in a file share mode that is less tolerant of breaks in connections to your data.  So it was the JET/ACE engine that corrupted, and not the fact of using MS Access.

So you always had the choice of continuing to use Access, but then can use something else for the back end database.

Just keep in mind though often people say you can replace access with SQL server, but they are often forgetting about the application development part. SQL server doesn't have forms or code to build the user interface with like access does. So with Access you build the user interface and now as noted this UI can be web based.

For web based you use the low cost office 365 (starts at $6 for hosting), or if you have SharePoint on site, you can use that.

However, at the end of the day I not aware of improvements of using the JET or now ACE data engine in a file share mode, but you were never limited to this choice when using Access anyway.